# Does the inflection point occur when both $f^{\prime}(x)=0$ and $f^{\prime\prime}(x)=0$ or just $f^{\prime\prime}(x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am asked to show that the inflection point of $p(t)=\frac{p_0}{p_0+(1-p_0) e^{
   -\alpha  t}}$ is the point where $p=1/2$. After solving $p^{\prime\prime}(t)=0$ for $t$ and substituting the value of $t$ in $p(t)$ I got $p(t)=1/2$ but when I substituted the same value of $t$ in $p^{\prime}(t)$, I got $p^{\prime}(t)=\alpha/4$. Does the inflection point require $p^{\prime}(t)=0$?

Comment: No. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point

Comment: No.  But it requires that $p''$ changes sign at the inflection point.  The "real" definition of "inflection point" is that the tangent line crosses the curve, so the curvature has to change at that point.

Answer (score 0):

An $\text{ inflection point}$, is defined as when $f''(x) =0$. At many cases, $f'(0)=0$, (meaning this is a critical point and an inflection point), but this does always have to be the case.

Comment: That is not the definition of an inflection point. If it were, then $f(x)=x^4$ would have an inflection point at the point $(0,0)$. An inflection point of a graph is a point of tangency of the graph where the concavity changes, or, as @B. Goddard puts it, a point of the graph where the tangent line crosses the graph.

Comment: I agree with your $defintion$, I was simply referring to how to $find$ it.

Comment: In any event, your point that $f^\prime$ does not have to be $0$ at the point of inflection was the salient point that OP needed to know. :)